# Create LAN session without Xbox Live in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

Is there a way to create a LAN session on XNA without having to own an Xbox Live account?

I'm currently running a snake game on XNA but whenever I create a LAN Session it asks me that the user is not 'Signed in to an Xbox Live account'.

So the question is, is there any other way to host a LAN session on C# without passing through XNA's restrictions?

Comment: If it's not possible, do I have to use C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is and you don't need to use C++ for that. You can either use C# .NET classes to build lan support from scratch (lots of work) or you can use lidgren library (used by [MonoGame](http://www.monogame.net/)): http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/

Hope this helps.